# Two by two table with count and percentage in R

Tags: r, dplyr

My data is like this:

```
   OnAntibiotic Gender
1          Yes    Male
2          Yes    Male
3          Yes  Female
4          Yes  Female
5          Yes  Female
6          Yes  Female
7          Yes  Female
8          Yes  Female
9          Yes  Female
10         Yes  Female
11         Yes    Male
12         Yes    Male
13         Yes    Male
14         Yes    Male
15           No Female
16           No Female
17           No Female
18           No   Male
19           No   Male
```

I would like to create a two by two table with count and percentage. Something like below:

```
       Yes (%)      No (%)   
Male    6 (42.8%)   2 (40%) 
Female  8 (57.1%)   3 (60%)
```

My code is:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Gender, OnAntibiotic) %>% 
  summarise(count=n())%>% 
  mutate(freq= n/sum(n))
```

Please help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: The data doesn't make sense. How have you got `No` count as 2 for Male and 3 for Female?

Comment: Sorry, I cut a part of my data. I've revised. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Gender,OnAntibiotic) %>% mutate(n=n()) %>% 
        group_by(OnAntibiotic) %>% distinct(OnAntibiotic,Gender,n)%>%
        mutate(Per=n/sum(n), np=paste0(n," (",round(Per*100,2)," %)")) %>%
        select(-n,-Per) %>% spread(OnAntibiotic,np)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Gender No       Yes        
  <fct>  <chr>    <chr>      
1 Female 3 (60 %) 8 (57.14 %)
2 Male   2 (40 %) 6 (42.86 %)
```

Comment: I deleted my answer, I had similar approach as above

Comment: This is the table format I am looking for. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

This is not quite the tabular format you asked for, but it contains the same data. You may also want to look into the functions `table` and `prop.table` as well:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(OnAntibiotic, Gender) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  mutate(freq = sprintf("%d (%0.1f%%)", count, 100*count/sum(count))) %>%
  select(-count)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   OnAntibiotic [2]
  OnAntibiotic Gender freq     
  <chr>        <chr>  <chr>    
1 No           Female 3 (60.0%)
2 No           Male   2 (40.0%)
3 Yes          Female 8 (57.1%)
4 Yes          Male   6 (42.9%)
```

It's worth noting that when you use `summarize` on a grouped data.frame - the most recent layer of grouping is stripped away. So when mutate was used above, it was summing over the counts of the `OnAntibiotic` groups, because the additional `gender` group was removed after the summarize call.

Edit: Updated with @Thomas' nice suggestion for the mutate clause. I'm hesitant to use the same `spread` verb @A. Suliman uses because the column names are not particularly informative, but if you're looking for a table for presentation purposes then I suppose you could just tack that on.

Comment: Perhaps `mutate(freq = sprintf("%d (%0.1f%%)", count, 100*count/sum(count)))` to get the formatted frequency and percent as a string.

Comment: It is very helpful. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You're on track, but the format you're after is not 'tidy' data. Look into the `tidyr` package to reformat your results. Take care to re-group your data!

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(Gender, OnAntibiotic) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  group_by(OnAntibiotic) %>%
  mutate(freq = n/sum(n)) %>%
  gather(measure, val) %>%
  spread(OnAntibiotic, val)
```

This will generate something close to your desired result. If you want the transposed version, you'll need to reach for the more generic (but more difficult) `reshape2` package.

NB: this answer targets result with numbers rather than printable strings

Comment: I will look into that. Thank you so much for your advice!